# Nuxt config dynamic stylesheet

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

How would I go about loading a stylesheet dynamically (in Nuxt.js) based on a UI button being clicked.

For example, I have this in my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
let org = 'default';

module.exports = {
    css: [
        '~/assets/sass/' + org + '/index.scss',
    ]
};
```

I omitted some of the code from this block, but what you are seeing is the main code needed to answer my question.

Essentially, I have a UI button that when I click it, I would like to change the value of `org` and have Nuxt load that stylesheet in place of the `default` one.

How would I go about doing something like this?

I was also tinkering around with doing something in my main `.vue` file like so:

```
export default {
   data() {
     return {
       skin: 'default',
     }
   },
   methods: {
     changeMe() {
       this.skin = 'other';
     }
   },
   head () {
      return {
        css: [
          '~/assets/sass/skins/' + this.skin + '/index.scss',
        ]
      }
   }
 }
```

Also, I was able to include my `default` skin by doing this:

```
<style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss">
  @import '~assets/sass/default/index';
</style>
```

It's to bad I couldn't make use of my `org` data variable and do something like this:

```
<style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss">
  @import '~assets/sass/' + this.org + '/index';
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this. You need to have defined CSS files for each organization. I can only imagine this being CSS files instead of scss files. Take a look the code below with working demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/l4on5508zm

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <button @click="swap">swap</button>
    <p v-text="cur" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        {
          rel: "stylesheet",
          href: `/${this.cur}.css`
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cur: "light"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    swap() {
      if (this.cur === "light") {
        this.cur = "dark";
      } else {
        this.cur = "light";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Looking at the code snippet above, you can bring in the css file to use on your page dynamically via the `head()` function. Think about it and check out the demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/l4on5508zm