# Setting body background image dynamically in nuxt on client side

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, head

I have the following Vue/Nuxt page that should have a background image depending on the querypath.

```
<template>
  <div>
    You searched from {{ game }} with word {{ search }}.
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      bodyAttrs: {
        style: 'background-image: url(\'' + this.backgroundUrl + '\');'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    backgroundUrl () {
      return 'http://external-cdn/' + this.$route.query.game + '/background.jpg'
    },
    search () {
      return this.$route.query.search
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If ssr is false, and the page is rendered client side, this idea works. It calculates the head bodyAttrs and calculates the correct background image. If I generate the page server-side, first, and then load the page with query params (for example http://site/search.html?game=doom&search=gun) the image URL is wrong: `http://external-cdn//background.jpg`.

I think the reason is that during generate the query path is empty and the head->bodyAttr is hydrated to be the empty path. When rendering the page it does not update the head anymore.

How can I force it to update the head on client-side again or what would be the vue/nuxt way of handling dynamic body background image?

One way is to use vanilla JS in `mounted` lifecycle hook (that is run on client side) like this:

```
  mounted () {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.backgroundUrl + ')'
  },
```

But would there be more vuey/nuxty way of achieving this?

Comment: Is the background going to change when the user is inside the page? For example, the page loaded with `http://site/some/bg.jpg` and then the user clicks on a button, and the background changes.

Comment: i think you should add require()

Comment: @ImanShafiei it doesn't have to change on a button click. Just loading the page the `this.$route.query.game` should contain the game name that is needed for loading the background image from correct place. Sibelle, you mean require for the image? The image is in another CDN service and not requirable as such.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating your code, finally, find the problem. You should use `return` for your `head()`:

```
head() {
    return {
        bodyAttrs: {
            style: 'background-image: url(\'' + this.backgroundUrl + '\');'
        }
    }
},


data() {
    backgroundUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/' + this.$route.query.link + '/',
}
```

If you want to try the above code, use links like `<YOUR-WEBSITE-URL>/?link=200/300` or any size you want.

Comment: I had forgotten the return statement from my code listing! I'm so sorry. I fixed the question to include the return there. Your finding was correct but still, with the return statement there, after generating the page with `nuxt build` the head is still not calculated at client-side. I am trying to replicate this in some code sandbox.

Comment: It is little hard to replicate this in sandbox environments as the page should be statically served. So, first generate a HTML page and then call that HTML page, through a static HTTP server, with the query parameters.

Comment: It works when the nuxt server handles the call as it can read the query.link correctly. But I don't have any server running. Just statically server HTML pages.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I think the problem because of `bodyAttrs`. Did you try `v-bind:style`? `v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${$route.query.link})`}"` . I think you should set this style on the main wrapper of your website in your `layout`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Setting it in the layout would be one path, yes. But then it wouldn't be in the `body` tag. And the need in this question is to put it into the body-tag, that is not accessible as such in nuxt.

Comment: Uhum, maybe importing style files base on the specific condition will help you and change the style of `body` at them. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354650/nuxt-config-dynamic-stylesheet